# Neo4j: can relationships be labeled?

Tags: neo4j

I ever used labels both for nodes and relationships.

According to official docs [labels are reserved to nodes](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#graphdb-neo4j-labels) while [properties](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#graphdb-neo4j-properties) are both for nodes and for relationships.

It looks strange to me. I have always used and queried relationships by their labels, e.g.

```
MATCH ()-[r:LabelName]-() return r;
```

Can relationships actually be labeled like it happens for nodes or are there differences?

Answer (score 0):

A Relationship has a 'Type' Not a Label

for example

```
match (c:contact)-[r]->(l:lead) return Distinct(type(r)) as DistinctRel
```

Would return the Distinct Relationships types between contacts and leads

```
╒═══════════╕
│DistinctRel│
╞═══════════╡
│Stakeholder│
├───────────┤
│Influencer │
└───────────┘
```

Yes, you can use Types like Labels to return KNOWN relationships.

```
match pth=(c:contact)-[r:Stakeholder]->(l:lead) return pth
```

would return contacts and the leads for which they have a Stakeholder relationship only.

Unlike Nodes which can have Multiple Labels, a Relationship can only have 1 Type.

A Relationship property would be something different again.

```
match pth=(c:contact {name:'Adrian Dumitrascu'})-[r:Stakeholder]->(l:lead)  set r.property=10
```

Would set a property called 'property' equal to 10 on the Stakeholder relationship between a Contact named Adrian and his leads.

```
match pth=(c:contact {name:'Adrian Dumitrascu'})-[r:Stakeholder]->(l:lead) return type(r) as Type, r.property

Type         r.property
Stakeholder  10
```

Comment: I do not understand why node's labels are different from rel's types. They seem identical except for the number of occurrences for each entity. Also node's properties and rel's properties look the same concept.

Comment: That one I don't have an answer for :( It might be determined by how they are used in the framework. Labels Group nodes into sets, Relationships are how you Traverse a graph.  Somewhere in there probably structurally lies the reason.  Either way, hope the example above was helpful.

Comment: I understand your example, I knew how to use Labels and rels, But I still do not understand structural difference between node's labels and rel's types